# How do I show old bitmap into DrawingView while painting

Tags: java, android

I want to edit my drawing painted image. I am getting a bitmap image and setting it into a canvas bitmap, but the old image is not appearing. I have tried using the `drawingView.refresh()` and `recycle()` methods, but couldn't make it work.

```
    private DrawingView mDrawingView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawing);

        if(datadtlimgsItem !=null && datadtlimgsItem.getImageStr() 
        !=null) {
            decodedString = Base64.decode(datadtlimgsItem.getImageStr(), 
            Base64.DEFAULT);
            decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, 
            decodedString.length);
            decodedByte = Util.resize(decodedByte, 400, 100);
            mDrawingView.canvasBitmap = decodedByte;
       }
    }

public class DrawingView extends View{

    // To hold the path that will be drawn.
    private Path drawPath;
    // Paint object to draw drawPath and drawCanvas.
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    // initial color
    private int paintColor = 0xff000000;
    private int previousColor = paintColor;
    // canvas on which drawing takes place.
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    // canvas bitmap
    public Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    // Brush stroke width
    private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
    // To enable and disable erasing mode.
    private boolean erase = false;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setUpDrawing();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize all objects required for drawing here.
     * One time initialization reduces resource consumption.
     */
    private void setUpDrawing(){
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        // Making drawing smooth.
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        // Initial brush size is medium.
        brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
        lastBrushSize = brushSize;
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, 
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // X and Y position of user touch.
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        // Draw the path according to the touch event taking place.
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (erase){
                    drawPaint.setXfermode(new 
    PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                }
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        // invalidate the view so that canvas is redrawn.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void setColor(String newColor){
        // invalidate the view
        invalidate();
        paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        previousColor = paintColor;
    }

    public void setBrushSize(float newSize){
        float pixelAmount = 
    TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        brushSize=pixelAmount;
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    }

    public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize){
        lastBrushSize=lastSize;
    }
    public float getLastBrushSize(){
        return lastBrushSize;
    }

    public void setErase(boolean isErase){
        //set erase true or false
        erase = isErase;
        if(erase) {
            drawPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            //drawPaint.setXfermode(new 
    PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        }
        else {
            drawPaint.setColor(previousColor);
            drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
        }
    }

    public void startNew(){
        drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

I have a view like Paint I want to show old image getting from activity in current view and then edit my image.

[image is blank but i need to show previous image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQaKG.png)

[here is saved image want to edit this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYA13.png)

I have a view like Paint I want to show old image getting from activity in current view and then edit my image. I have a view like Paint I want to show old image getting from activity in current view and then edit my image. I have a view like Paint I want to show old image getting from activity in current view and then edit my image. I have a view like Paint I want to show old image getting from activity in current view and then edit my image. I have a view like Paint I want to show old image getting from activity in current view and then edit my image.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        if (canvasBitmap == null){

            canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }
```